Mechanics of wheel with tire
Exploring the mechanics of wheel with tire,
in Massimo Guiggiani's book "The science of vehicle dynamics" 2018,
in chapter 2.8.4 kinematic conditions are provided for $F_y=0$ and $M_z=0$ as resultant couple in contact patch, quote:

However, the fulfillment of both conditions (2.43) and (2.45)
together, that is $F_y = 0$ and $M_z = 0$, yields these results $$ V r o y (h, \gamma ) = V r c y (h, \gamma ) = 0    \tag{2.46} $$ $$ ωrz = −\omega c \sin \gamma (1 − \epsilon r) \tag{2.47} $$

How exactly were these results yielded?
If someone provides link to paper with such analysis I would be grateful.
